# How to perform an Inner join on a result set of another sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to pull last two months data using the following tables : 
I've reached this far :

`select * from requests r
    INNER JOIN request_status rs
    ON r.id = rs.request_id 
    where r.customer_id = <some-customer-id> 
    AND r.created_time_stamp 
    BETWEEN '2016-011-01 00:00:00.000000' 
    AND '2017-01-05 00:00:00.000000' limit 10`

The problem is I'm not sure how to put another inner join on the result set of above query. What I have to achieve is perform an inner join on the result set of above query and pull some data from that result set. Any help how to go about?

1. requests :

`+-----+--------------------+
| id  | created_time_stamp |
+-----+--------------------+
| 123 | 12:23:00           |
+-----+--------------------+`

2. request_status :

`+----+------------+-------------+
| id | request_id | customer_id |
+----+------------+-------------+
| 12 |        123 |        3453 |
+----+------------+-------------+`

3. request_process :

`+----+-------------+------------+
| id | customer_id | process_id |
+----+-------------+------------+
| 12 |        3453 |         23 |
+----+-------------+------------+`

EDIT 1 :

Consider the following tables with the fields listed after the colon :

1. push_requests : id, customer_id, created_time_stamp
2. push_status : id, request_id
3. subscribers : id, customer_id, is_inactive

NOTE : request_id in push_status is foreign key to push_request's id

What I want to achieve within the query:

1. Pull records from push_requests with customer_id A between so and so created_time_stamp.
2. Join this with push_status table based on the foreign key.
3. Join the result-set of step 1 and 2 with subscriptions table.

What output I'm expecting : A final result set with entire rows of push_requests, push_status and an appended column that shows number of subscribers having is_inactive value of 0.

Comment: What modification do you need to make to your current query?

Comment: I want perform an inner join on the result set of above query.

Comment: If you are using sql server use CTE ,[docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: OK...but to _which_ table do you want to join?

Comment: The third table listed above request_process based on the customer_id field.

Comment: `INNER JOIN request_process rp ON rs.customer_id = rp.customer_id` after the `ON` in your query does not work?

Comment: `'2016-011-01 00:00:00.000000'`...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you can't just add another join condition to your query, to join to the `request_process` table:

```
SELECT *
FROM requests r
INNER JOIN request_status rs
    ON r.id = rs.request_id
INNER JOIN request_process rp
    ON rs.customer_id = rp.customer_id
WHERE r.customer_id = <some-customer-id> AND
      r.created_time_stamp BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000000' AND
                                   '2017-01-05 00:00:00.000000'
LIMIT 10
```

Note that I corrected a typo in the timestamp `'2016-01-01 00:00:00.000000'`.

Comment: Some thing is wrong with the query, it throws same row ten times.

Comment: It's not the same row, and you never gave us any sample data or output, likely the cause for the downvote.  What output did you expect?

Comment: Fair enough, updating the question in some time. I had corrected the typo.